# One Hot Encoding by get dummies issue

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering

I have created function to encode my features by OneHotEncoding technique:

```
def One_hot_encoding(columns, final_df):
    for fields in columns:
        dum_df = pd.get_dummies(final_df[fields], columns=fields, prefix="is", drop_first=True)
        final_df = final_df.join(dum_df)
        final_df.drop(columns=fields, inplace=True)
    return final_df
```

I called the function by bellow code:

`df_final = One_hot_encoding(golden_features_list1, final_df)`

My golden_features list = list(['Gender', 'Country'])

final_df is dataframe consist of columns = ['Gender', 'Country', 'SalePrice']

**When I tried to call the function it is running forever!..I am forced to restart my Jupiter notebook server. What is wrong with the code?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see these posts on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially the tips on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't tell what's going wrong without more information about your issue, especially how you define `golden_features_list1` and `final_df`.

Comment: How large is your dataframe?  Try smaller bits of it first.

Comment: @Scott Boston My Actual dataframe contains nearly 78 features. May me that could be a problem.